# can't access win 7 pro network shares from 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I can see the network identified as "Windows network" but when I click on the icon  "File is empty" is displayed.  I can also see the network displayed under Networks (as Windows Network), with the same result "File is empty". All was ok on 16.04 until I updated. How do I fix this in 18.04?
I have been digging further into this issue, while I can access the internet ok using Netgear A6210 USB wifi stick, I don't have access to the windows network.  I have a Epson printer with sd card and usb ports fitted which is on the wifi and worked with 18.04 until I tested the card port directly by connecting to the printer via the USB port. Now I cannot print from Ubuntu via wifi. I have successfully created 2 shared folders, user restricted on a separate HDD which I can see from the Windows machines but cannot log in even with the user passwords I have set. I still cannot gain access to the Windows network from ubuntu as it is asking for a network password, I never set or have one on the Windows network so I suspect that this is asking for the ubuntu network password but  i don't remember setting one and I have tried my ubuntu login and my windows login but all fails. My workgroup is set as WORKGROUP.Heree is the dump of /etc/samba/smb.conf file after I have used testparm

## Global parameters

[global]
    dns proxy = No
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    syslog = 0
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb

[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0700
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes

[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers

[linux share]
    path = /dev/sdb5/Linux Bill
    read only = No
    valid users = Bill Stanowski
I now notice I have only one linux share listed, how do I add 2 off?
1 Jan 2019. Totally removed Netgear A6210 USB WiFi as each Linux update overwrote the setup. I reinstalled the PCI Wifi card and all runs well.

7 Jan, 2019. I have removed the windows network password requirement from the Win 7 Pro PC and have access from that PC. Interestingly, the Win 7 Home Premium PC needs a Network password, but gives me access across the network, but I still cannot access the Windows network from the Linux machine. Under Windows Network Properties, I get "The permissions of Windows Network could not be determined." I have tried turning off the AVS ESET package on Win 7 Pro but makes no difference.
Thank you.